# I've heard for virtual Windows Servers that Linux is the best host, which software is currently recommended for this?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization

Let me know if my hearsay is inaccurate, otherwise what software would you recommend? Right now we use Parallels Virtuozzo which hosts Windows on Windows but honestly, it ain't so great. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Best for your particular situation is going to be highly dependent on *your particular situation*. Hyper-V, ESXi, VirtualBox, KVM, Xen, etc, might each be the "best" for you or the worst.

Comment: Isn't Hyper-V for Windows hosts?

Comment: Hyper-V Server is a complete hypervisor (based on Windows Server), guests aren't specially limited to any particular OS. There is also a Hyper-V Role which can be added to Windows Server 2008/R2, this is very similar but not the same thing. ESXi and Hyper-V Server are (very) roughly comparably products (ESXi being based on Linux, like KVM and others; Xen, Virtual Box and others can be based on several different OSes. What you're asking has no simple answer. VMWare's ESXi is the most popular hypervisor currently, but that doesn't make it "best" for all things.

Comment: I was under the impression that Linux was more stable than Windows, and more secure.

Comment: @Ryan, that really hasn't been true for years, if it ever was true.